# Unable to do update table from Apex 5 button Error mentions Cannot Insert NULL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex-5

Hi People of the Palace

I am not having luck here and tried a lot of things and seems as if I am not able to get the value from the field which needs to update.

There are 2 fields within Apex 5 which I want to update if something if the value is changed from default. :QUANTITY which is a text field inside of a Tabular form and :DISC which is also a text field in the same row.
There can be single or multiple rows to that needs to be updated and this is usually where you set the option "updated rows and columns only"

The table SALES_TEMP does has columns `ID`, `NAME`, `QUANTITY_TO_SELL`, `DISCOUNT`.

The PL/SQL code that is assigned in the process to do this update is as follows.

```
BEGIN
update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL=:QUANTITY, DISCOUNT=:DISC;
end;
```

When I try and update the fields, it will return with

> Cannot insert NULL into QUANTITY_TO_SELL

and similar with the DISCOUNT field.

Now I know there is nothing wrong with the query because if I do this:

```
BEGIN
update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL='2', DISCOUNT='5';
end;
```

It does in fact update the table, but it will then do this update to all rows in the table because I have no where clause.

I have had a look through the different options and cannot seem to find why it does not select the data from the fields. My main issue is, I have an exact same query running doing an insert which works.

Also from Apex's Sql Command line option if I run.

```
update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL=:QUANTITY, DISCOUNT=:DISC;
```

I get a popup requesting values for `:QUANTITY` and `:DISC` and it then updates the columns so something tells me that this is not getting the values from these text fields.

The SQL command to add to populate the fields are

```
select ID, NAME, QUANTITY_TO_SELL as QUANTITY, DISCOUNT as DISC from SALES_TEMP;
```

Obviously each gets assigned as `:ID`, `:NAME` `:QUANTITY` and `:DISC` in apex.

Comment: This seems to be a complicated way of asking why `:QUANTITY` and `:DISC` are not getting populated in your form when you think they should.

Comment: If we do not add code, people down vote the question, if we add the code and complicate it, then we get told we are complicating a question :)

Comment: Presumably the problem lies in populating `:QUANTITY` and `:DISC`. I don't see any code for that.

Comment: @William, sorry to say but you are trying to be difficult and not helpful at all.

Comment: I am trying to find out what the issue is. All we know is that `:QUANTITY` and `:DISC` fields in your Apex application have null values, and this is causing subsequent update statements to fail. The update itself and the PL/SQL that calls it don't seem to be the problem, unless the correct values are somehow not being passed.

Comment: The reason the fields are not populated is because the process is not associated with the tabular form. This is determined with the fact that a hardcoded value does infact add into the table using the same button. This tells me that the process does not know where to get these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are using Tabular form I suggest you ensure that the following is set.

1. On the procedure (in processing), Ensure you have the Tabular form selected.
2. Ensure the Condition "When button is pressed" is set to use the button you want to assign this process to.

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 solved the issue. I am unsure why though as I ave an exact same query with the tabular form not selected. The other issue now is I need to be able to set only the changed rows and not all rows. any ideas? Thanks a mill.

Comment: The update issue is another problem. Will need to find something unique to match the row where the change occurred on the form.

Answer (score 0):

1. in Oracle update clause should ALWAYS have where clause, because oracle will update all data in the table without the WHERE clause.
2. The cannot insert null error occurs when you are trying to insert in one of the table attributes NULL, where parameter set to NOT NULL, so in your case try to use NVL function, to avoid this issue, I ques that the **NAME** atribute should not be null.

try to modify your code like this:

```
update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL = :QUANTITY, 
    DISCOUNT = :DISC,
    NAME = nvl(:NAME,'empty')
where ID = :ID;
```

in this case it will update only one column.

The Oracle/PLSQL **NVL** function lets you substitute a value when a null value is encountered.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. My problem is the cannot insert NULL into QUANTITY_TO_SELL. The command does work manually or when hardcoding the value, the issue is that when I click the update button with my code (And yours) it does not update the table. I suspect that it is not seeing any value in `:DISCOUNT` and `:QUANTITY`

Comment: I am not familiar with the APEX, but I think that this is some kind of Oracle framework, so what I can suggest you to do is make a procedure in Oracle and call that procedure from APEX passing the parameters, or it could be that there are different parameters name in APEX then yours, so make sure what are the parameters name. update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL = nvl(:QUANTITY,'empty'),
    DISCOUNT = :DISC,
    NAME = :NAME
where ID = :ID;

Comment: update SALES_TEMP 
set QUANTITY_TO_SELL = nvl(:QUANTITY,'empty'), 
    DISCOUNT = :DISC,
    NAME = :NAME,'empty'
where ID = :ID;

Comment: @TheName. That will only substitute the NULL value and get rid of the error message which is not his problem. He is wants to update the table and not just get rid off errors.